# If a company "creates value" for its users do the users "consume it"?

Tags: word-choice

If a company is a producer of a product we have consumers who 'consume' it. So we have a 
"producer-consumer" noun relationship.

But if a company "creates" value it can be called a value-creator. So what would that make the users who "derive" value from it? "Derivators?" Sounds a bit weird. Would they also be called consumers?

So what would be a right word to use for the following analogy:

```
Producer:Consumer::Value-Creator: ?
```

**EDIT**: I don't wish to state if it's business-wise right or wrong. I want to know language wise what would be the appropriate noun-phrase to use in this regard.

E.g.: Google creates value for it's users by offering seamless search, Apple for usability, Microsoft for platform etc. etc. I am using 'Value' in the subjective sense and not necessarily money only.

Comment: Can you give an example of a value-creator?

Comment: The concept of "company as value-creator" is really only appropriate when you think of it as *value for the company's shareholders*. The "customers" don't exactly have any connection with that "value" unless it eventually leads to lower prices (which will normally happen because of competetion, not because the company has made so much money it's becoming embarrassed, and wishes to give some of the money back to the original customers).

Comment: Is it like a *value-add* situation?  For example, a company that doesn't own any fiber themselves, but offers connectivity to carriers and services on top of that?

Comment: @combread ninja: It's difficult to tell what is being asked here, however there is an objectively correct value of an object that can be determined irrespective of individual value judgements, such as by analyzing the amount of labor incurred in producing the object.

Comment: Companies, also, do not have "users." They have customers or clients, they have partners and vendors, they have employees and investors— but only their products and services have *users*.

Comment: @Carlo_R.: I think you're displaying your "left-wing" leanings there. A more "right-wing" person would probably say the *value* of a thing isn't related to the cost of production - it's entirely a matter of *how much someone is willing to pay for it*.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Creation of value** can apply to *shareholders*, *customers* or *employees*. See, e.g. [this article](http://www.pegasuscom.com/levpoints/valuecreate.html).

I think a good term for those to whom this value can be conveyed is **beneficiaries**.